# Comparar duas listas encadeadas e retornar se são iguais ou diferentes

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Venho tentando comparar duas listas simplesmente encadeadas e retornar se são iguais ou diferentes mas não tô conseguindo acertar a função comparar, ela só compara o último valor inserido se está igual ou não, se altero os outros aparece que tá tudo igual!

```
 void Comparar(no *l1, no *l2) 
 { 
    while (l1->prox!= NULL){
    l1= l1;
     while(l2->prox!= NULL){
        l2= l2;
          if(l1->info == l2->info){

                 printf("Iguais\n\n");
          } else
                  printf("Diferentes\n\n");
    system("pause");    
    }     

}

}
```

O programa completo é esse:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct no {
  int info;
  struct no* prox;
}no;



no* cria_no (void) {
  return NULL;
}



no* inserir (no* lst, int v) {
  no* novo = (no*) malloc(sizeof(no));
  novo->info = v;
  novo->prox = lst;
  return novo;
}


 void Comparar(no *l1, no *l2) 
 { 
    while (l1->prox!= NULL){
    l1= l1;
     while(l2->prox!= NULL){
        l2= l2;
          if(l1->info == l2->info){

                 printf("Iguais\n\n");
          } else
                  printf("Diferentes\n\n");
    system("pause");    
    }     

}

}
int main (void)
{
  no* lst1; 
  no* lst2; 

  lst1 = cria_no(); 
  lst1 = inserir(lst1, 21); 
  lst1 = inserir(lst1, 45); 
  lst1 = inserir(lst1, 10); 

  lst2 = cria_no(); 
  lst2 = inserir(lst2, 21); 
  lst2 = inserir(lst2, 45); 
  lst2 = inserir(lst2, 5); 


    printf("\nAS LISTAS SAO:\n");

    Comparar(lst1,lst2);


}
```

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Edite a pergunta pra adicionar a tag da linguagem que você está usando (provavelmente é `c`)

Comment: Você tem que partir do pressuposto de que são iguais colocando uma variável como verdadeira, testar a igualdade elemento a elemento e se forem diferentes ou tiverem quantidades de elementos diferentes colocar a variável como falsa. Ao final  imprimir se são iguais ou diferentes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Alguns comentários sobre seu código

1. A formatação não está legal. Pesquise na internet sobre boas práticas de indentação e organização de código, e veja se o seu editor possui um comando para formatar automaticamente.
2. A função `main` foi declarada do tipo `int`, mas não está retornando nada. O header `stdlib.h` possui duas constantes, a `EXIT_SUCCESS` e a `EXIT_FAILURE`, que você pode usar como retorno da `main`. Retorne `EXIT_SUCCESS` se a execução do programa foi bem sucedida, senão retorne `EXIT_FAILURE`.
3. Você está usando o `malloc` para alocar memória, mas não está usando o `free` para liberar a memória alocada. **Você deve chamar o `free` para todos os ponteiros retornados pelo `malloc`**. Isso é *muito* importante.
4. Sempre que você chamar o `malloc` **você precisa verificar se o retorno não é `NULL`**. Se o `malloc` retornar `NULL` significa que ele não conseguiu alocar a memória solicitada. Isso é *muito* importante também.
5. Não precisa dar cast no retorno do `malloc`.

### Agora vamos para o problema da comparação

A sua função `Comparar` printa uma mensagem na tela *para cada valor comparado*, só que tem um `system("pause");` dentro do laço, então ele pausa a execução após a primeira comparação.

Você deve iterar por ambas as listas simultaneamente. Retorne `false` se encontrar dois elementos diferentes ou se uma das listas acabar antes da outra, senão retorne `true`.

Programa completo:

(Sem warnings com `gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c11`)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define retornar_failure_caso_null(expr)             \
    if ((expr) == NULL)                              \
    {                                                \
        fprintf(stderr, "Falha ao alocar memória!"); \
        return EXIT_FAILURE;                         \
    }

typedef struct no
{
    int info;
    struct no *prox;
} no;

no *cria_no(void)
{
    return NULL;
}

no *inserir(no *lst, int v)
{
    no *novo = malloc(sizeof(no));

    if (novo == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    novo->info = v;
    novo->prox = lst;

    return novo;
}

bool comparar(no *lista1, no *lista2)
{
    no *atual1 = lista1;
    no *atual2 = lista2;

    while (atual1 != NULL && atual2 != NULL)
    {
        if (atual1->info != atual2->info)
        {
            return false;
        }

        atual1 = atual1->prox;
        atual2 = atual2->prox;
    }

    return atual1 == NULL && atual2 == NULL;
}

void liberar_memoria(no *lista)
{
    no *atual = lista;

    while (atual != NULL)
    {
        no *proximo = atual->prox;

        free(atual);

        atual = proximo;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    no* lista1 = cria_no();

    retornar_failure_caso_null(lista1 = inserir(lista1, 21));
    retornar_failure_caso_null(lista1 = inserir(lista1, 45));
    retornar_failure_caso_null(lista1 = inserir(lista1, 10));

    no* lista2 = cria_no();

    retornar_failure_caso_null(lista2 = inserir(lista2, 21));
    retornar_failure_caso_null(lista2 = inserir(lista2, 45));
    retornar_failure_caso_null(lista2 = inserir(lista2, 5));

    if (comparar(lista1, lista2))
    {
        puts("São iguais");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("São diferentes");
    }

    liberar_memoria(lista1);
    liberar_memoria(lista2);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Obrigada pelas informações, ajudou muito com o problema e vou dar uma estudada pra melhorar minha formatação. Foquei muito no comparar e esqueci de todo o resto rs